# How to open iCal to a specific event/date in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, macos, calendar, icalendar

I can't seem to find a way in Mountain Lion to successfully open ical in code.

I'd prefer to not use applescript, and use cocoa. Let me know if there is an api I'm missing.

Currently I just use:

```
[[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] launchApplication:@"iCal"];
```

Thank you!!!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to just launch the application, then it's basically what you're doing. There is some further information [in the docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSWorkspace_Class/Reference/Reference.html) and a nice writeup [here](http://theocacao.com/document.page/183).

However, if you want to integrate with calendars in your code, maybe you should use the [Event Kit Framework](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/EventKitProgGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html)

Comment: Thanks. My goal is to open iCal to a specific date or specific event. The code I have successfully opens iCal, but to today's date. I'm using the Event Kit to interact and pull the events into my application, but I can't seem to get an iCal button to link back to iCal and open the same event that I pulled in. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I used the following code:

```
-(void)show:(NSString*)eventUid InCalendar:(NSString*)calUid {
  iCalApplication *iCal = [SBApplication applicationWithBundleIdentifier:(@"com.apple.iCal")];
  [iCal activate];

  SBElementArray *sbCalendars = [iCal calendars];
  if(sbCalendars != nil && [sbCalendars objectWithID:calUid] != nil) {
    iCalCalendar *sbCalendar = [sbCalendars objectWithID:calUid];
    if([sbCalendar events] != nil){
      iCalEvent *sbCalEvent = [[sbCalendar events] objectWithID:eventUid];
      if(sbCalEvent != nil){
        NSLog(@"%@", sbCalEvent);
        [sbCalEvent show];
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Which worked for quite a time but stopped working since they introduced Sandbox. I filed a bug more than a year ago but got no useable answer from Apple.